# Ionic(Angular) and Angular projects stop live-reloading code edits after a while when served

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

When I run `ng serve` or `ionic serve` for my ionic and angular projects, the live-reloading feature works for a while. However, after an hour or so it stops working. I can tell because I run into an error, make a change to the code, and notice that it is the same. Then I look into the source files of the project via inspect element to see my changes have not been made. So, I restart my angular or ionic project. Usually, that fixes things. However, this is quite an annoying problem. I have experienced it twice today, once on an ionic project and once on an angular project. Is anyone else having this experience or knows how to fix it? It has been going on for a few weeks now at least for me.

Comment: Follow up: This only happens on occasion and when it does happen, I have been running the project for at least 30 mins. Also, I tend to serve my angular and ionic projects for a long time (sometimes I go to bed and forget that they are still served).

Comment: Are you sure you're not 'fixing' the files from the rendered www folder which gets rewritten? Just curious